# Not able to get value from dropDown when clicking ENTER

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

I've been trying to get this to work for hours now, but still no luck :(. I have this basic reactive form that if I either hit **"ENTER"** or click on **"Search"** button I can see the result of the form values in the console.

**Issue:**

1) When I select a value from **dropDown** and then hit **Enter** right away I can't console out the form values, but if I type either firstName or Lastname and then hit **ENTER** it works.

Here my CODE: [**LIVE DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8wvrkv?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with `primeng` dropdown `p-dropdown`. By default `enter` doesn't work how a standard select box work.

To get this fix you can use `(keyup.enter)` in `p-dropdown`.

```
<p-dropdown (keyup.enter)="onFormSubmit($event)"  [options]="cities" formControlName="currentCity" placeholder = "city" optionLabel="label"></p-dropdown>
```

working copy is here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k7o6r7

Comment: Thank you for your help bro!

Answer (score -1):

Just a little change in onFormSubmit. 
See here:

[image]

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zous5f

Comment: You can insert pictures into the post without linking them. It would be helpful to do so.